# Now that we have a global inbox, do we still need the Top Bar notifications?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox, notification-bar

Now that we have the global inbox I feel that we get far too many notifications on the family of sites.

I had 1 new comment today, and I got a Global Inbox notification, the envelope lit up, an I had the Top Bar notification.  I don't think that we need the Top Bar notification on sites anymore.

### Glossary:

**Global Inbox:** The 'inbox' tab located in the StackExchange drop down menu.
**Envelope:** The white envelope next to the user's name on each site.
**Top Bar:** The notification bar that appears on a site if you have new notifications.

Comment: What? You don't get an email notification for every comment? I have to make a feature request ...

Comment: the inbox doesn't show favourites-modifications, and if there's more than one reply on one question the inbox only links to the most recent one

Comment: @Tobias, True, but the lit envelope will tell you the same information once you visit that page.  I just don't think we need both the envelope and the notification bar.

Comment: If I read it from the global inbox my envelope doesn't lit

Answer (score 9):

-1! Yes, we do! Please don't take away my top bar notifications!

I like to do all my business on one site at a time; it's just how I keep mentally organized. I might look over all my notifications in the global inbox when I hit my first site of the day (SO), but I'm not going to check out any of the non-SO links until I get done looking over the latest SO questions that are unrelated to my notifications.

There's nothing wrong with using SE another way, but please keep the site-specific notifications for people who are like me.

EDIT:
Initially, I thought that the OP was referring to the envelope icon that sits in each site's gray "top bar," and by extension, the page for which the envelope icon is a link. OP has clarified that he meant the colored bar that looks like the one that announces newly earned badges. I would be more okay with losing that bar, though I don't think the introduction of the global inbox is a good reason for taking that bar away.

Comment: Why do you need 2 notifications on one site? A lit envelope tells you as much as the notification bar, or am I wrong? It's not like OP proposes to keep only the inbox.

Comment: @Joris, I thought that was exactly what the OP was proposing. Could you please clarify, @jjnguy?

Comment: @Popular Demand : The OP clearly states even in the title that it is about drop down notifications. Dropping this leaves still both the envelope and the inbox. I can't see what's not clear about that?

Comment: @Joris, the title does not mention "drop down" at all, so I don't know what you're looking at. But the dropdown notification _is_ the global inbox... I thought that was a typo.

Comment: @Popular, I'd like to only remove the notification bar, not the envelope.

Comment: @jjn, _ohhhh_, the "notification bar"! When you said "top bar notification" I thought you meant the envelope icon, because it's in the site's "top bar."

Comment: @pop, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I meant the topper bar.  The bar that appears on top of the top bar in some situations.

Comment: And this kind of confusion is *exactly* why getting [a *real* name for that thingadongdong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51176/messages-notifications-warnings-are-they-different-or-all-the-same-which-one) is a good idea!

Comment: This is linked to in Grace's post, but it turns out the glossary I was thinking of creating [also already exists](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms).

Answer (score 2):

I think we should at least wait until all the bugs are worked out of the Global Inbox, and the holes in the system figured out.  I'm still not sure of everything that it covers.