# Is it possible to turn off the notification bars?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, notification-bar

It would be a nice feature to allow people to select for which events they want a notification in the notification bar. There is quite some frustration about that notification bar, and for me it also gets more in the way than anything else. Yet, other people really like that feature, so removing it like proposed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65809/now-that-we-have-a-global-inbox-do-we-still-need-the-top-bar-notifications) is not an option.

I was looking already for a way to turn it off for my account, but that's not possible apparently. Could this feature be implemented? Ideally, one would be able to indicate for which topics he/she wants the notification bar to show up - or not.

PS : if this is implemented already but I'm too stupid to find it, please enlighten me.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65809/now-that-we-have-a-global-inbox-do-we-still-need-the-top-bar-notifications

Comment: related, but not the same. I don't want to get rid of notification bars, I just want to be able to turn them off personally.

Comment: Amen. I hate that damn bar.

Comment: Even I, who loves notifications in general, also *dislike* that bar!

Comment: Bump. I'd probably be okay with the bar if it didn't fade in and animate, to be honest. That's the worst part. You're already scanning the page content and then if you're quick maybe you want to click somewhere and just before you can, the entire page content abruptly shifts down several pixels. **Very**, **very** frustrating.

Comment: I want to vote for this too. I think it can be fun if you're in that mood, and it is engaging. But I find when I am in a quest to find an answer, the notification is distracting, and I get off track. Just being able to turn it off would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now removed; see https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/

Comment: Let me thank you for this. Let me thank you for this again. ah, I love you guys and girls :-)