# How do I disable the badge notifications on all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, support, badges, notifications, gamification

While I love the Stack Exchange network and Stack Overflow especially, I started to be really annoyed about having too many badge notifications, especially from the new sites where I go only occasionally.

I think that **this amount of gamification is too much for me to handle**, and I want to be able to **opt-out** from using it **but still be able to use the site**.

Comment: There isn't a way, unfortunately. If you decide to make this a [meta-tag:feature-request] I'd support it. In fact I'd support anything that has "disable" & "notifications" in it.

Comment: Now is a feature request! BTW, I am so disperate, that I would gladly accept a grease-monkey solution, too.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123841/how-to-hide-gamification-features-such-as-badges-comments-names-and-reputati

Comment: Related and maybe duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65821/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-the-notification-bars

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Not duplicate, I want other notifications but not the gamification ones. I don't need a **carrot** do activate on these sites, I just do it because it helps me (including helping others).

Comment: @Sorin it says *allow people to select for which events they want a notification in the notification bar* :)